# JavaFX TableView Nested Property Binding

Tags: javafx, binding, properties, nested, tableview

I have a list of objects which containing lists of a complex data type and I need to bind these properties to my TableView.
My entities are looking like this:

```
public class Customer
{
   StringProperty property1;
   StringProperty property2;
   ....
   List<Contract> contracts;
}


public class Contract
{
    StringProperty property1;
    StringProperty property2;
    ....
}
```

My observableArrayList contains a list of Customer which contains a list of Contract.
Getting the Customer properties is easy:

```
sampleColumn1.setCellValueFactory(celldata -> celldata.getValue().sampleProperty1());
sampleColumn2.setCellValueFactory(celldata -> celldata.getValue().sampleProperty2());
...
```

But I can't get the properties of the Contract list..
Currently I do the following workaround:

```
PropertyValueFactory<Customer, List<Contract>> contractFactory = new PropertyValueFactory<>("contracts");
contractIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(contractFactory);
contractIdColumn.setCellFactory(celldata -> new TableCell<Customer>, List<Contract>>(){
@Override
public void updateItem(List<Contract> contracts, boolean empty){
    super.updateItem(contracts, empty);
    if(empty)
    setText("");            
    else
    setText(contracts.stream().map(Contract::getContractId)
   .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
}
});
```

But this code is dirty, does somebody know an approach to do this with cellValueFactory and lambda expressions?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cell value factory is simply a `Callback` taking a `CellDataFeatures` and returning an appropriate observable value, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
contractIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellDataFeatures -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellDataFeatures.getValue().contracts.stream()
    .map(Contract::getContractId)
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))));
```

Note that if you were to use an `ObservableList` instead of a list you could use [Bindings.createStringBinding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createStringBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-) so that the value would update if the list updates but the `Customer` element does not change.

Comment: Well thanks for your reply, with this approach I can't get my BooleanProperties :/  I actually have a ObservableList, how do I call the Properties with bindings?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the code you have is too bad. The important thing here is to separate the *data* displayed in the cell (provided by the `cellValueFactory`) from how the data is presented (provided by the `cellFactory`), and you have that. The data is clearly the list of contracts, so you certainly want

```
TableColumn<Customer, List<Contract>> contractIdColumn ;
```

and you need the cell value to be an `ObservableValue<List<Contract>>`, which you can do either as you have it:

```
contractIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("contracts"));
```

or, in a more type-safe way, with

```
contractIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().getContracts()));
```

Then your current cell factory will display the list of contracts as text, with each contract ID on a new line. You could readily modify the cell factory (without changing the cell value factory) to use, e.g. a `ListView<Contract>`:

```
contractIdColumn.setCellFactory(celldata -> new TableCell<Customer>, List<Contract>>(){

    private final ListView<Contract> listView = new ListView<>();

    @Override
    public void updateItem(List<Contract> contracts, boolean empty){
        super.updateItem(contracts, empty);
        if(empty)
            setGraphic(null);            
        else {
            listView.getItems().setAll(contracts);
            setGraphic(listView);
        }
    }

});
```

(just a rough example; you may need to style the cells to fit the list view properly, and this assumes `Contract` has an appropriate `toString()`; you may need to set a cell factory on the `ListView`s too, etc).